# How to print debug messages in dynamic web project in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, http, web

I am working on a simple dynamic web project in eclipse. I am getting HTTP 404 error. I want to debug my program using debug messages. please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have tried printing using System.out.println. But I don't see anything being printed on console.

Comment: Use some logging framework instead of s.o.println(). Also, some code would help others understanding your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a logger such as `log4j` and configure it to use `FileAppender` to send the logs to a file. Here is a simple tutorial to help you with basic log4j configuration:

http://www.mkyong.com/logging/log4j-log4j-properties-examples/

Answer (score 0):

Http 404 : Either you are using wrong url or the resource (page, image, js file) you are requesting does not exist.

As suggested by Juned Ahsan, use logging in your servlet class